# Removing the cover for this light fixture

Tags: light-fixture

There are three prongs that hold a dome shape cover together. One of the prong is spring loaded.

Normally, you would push the cover to the direction of the spring loaded prong, then the spring would extend enough and you can take out the cover. However, for this one the prong did not extend enough to slip the cover out. The spring loaded prong moves about 1 cm, but that is not enough for the cover to fall off.  I tried to push it very hard, but it still does not extend enough.

Each prong is screwed from the inside, so I cannot take it off.

Is there some special way of taking the cover off?

[image: light fixture]

Comment: push the springloaded prong and push the dome the other way

Answer (score 3):

Pull the spring-loaded prong away from the dome, and tip the dome below it - then pull the dome away from the other two prongs. Don't push the spring-loaded prong with the dome.

- Simple geometry says that the required distance of movement to get
  one prong clear is considerably less than what's need to clear the
  ones at 120 degrees from it.
- Trigonometry quantifies that to about half, if I'm constructing the
  problem correctly in my head.

Comment: I tried this, but it still does not extend enough.

Comment: The springs on these prongs are often quite strong. Use more force to pull them out — you won't break anything.